# all values of $ \tan^2 3x \cos^2 x - 4\tan 3x \sin 2x + 16\sin^2 x$ lie in interval

Tags: trigonometry, self-learning

For $0 < x < \frac{\pi}{6}$ , all values of

$ \tan^2 3x  \cos^2 x - 4\tan 3x \sin 2x + 16\sin^2 x$ lie in interval

A. $(0 , \frac{121}{36})$

B.$(1,\frac{121}{9})$

C.$(-1,0)$

D.None of above

Now i completed square and write as $(\tan 3x \cos x - 4\sin x)^2$. How do i proceed? Thanks

Comment: You missed minus sign in the square.

Comment: @VikrantDesai Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The answer is $D$ since you have a perfect square and hence the value has to be positive. Indeed, let $f(x)=(\tan 3x \cos x - 4\sin x)^2$.

For $x\to 0$ the value of $f(x)$ tends to $0$. This leaves you with possibilities: A) or D).

Now remark that $f(x)$ is continuous in the interval you are considering and that for $x\to\frac{\pi}{6}$ the function $f(x)\to\infty$

Hence the only option is D).

Comment: But sir ,my textbook states answer to be a

Comment: Did you forget to add some informations in the statement? Otherwise I think that the answer of the textbook is wrong.

Comment: i added everything

Comment: Is it possible that there are some parenthesis? I mean that $\tan(3x)\cos x$ is in fact $\tan(3x\cos x)$ ? Because if this is the case then the answer is A)